# Javascript: creating an array out of another

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array-snapshot out of Firebase, which contains the entries of my application. Among other information there is a a timestamp called "referenceDate":

```
entry [0] { referenceDate: 2017-08-03,...
entry [1] { referenceDate: 2017-08-02,...
entry [2] { referenceDate: 2017-08-01,...
entry [3] { referenceDate: 2017-07-03,...
entry [4] { referenceDate: 2017-07-02,...
```

I want to output the entries grouped under a headline by month and year like this

```
08.2017
03.08.2017
02.08.2017
01.08.2018
07.2017
03.07.2017
02.07.2017
```

My idea is to loop over the array-snapshot and create another nested one which looks like this:

```
 {"monthYear": "08.2017":[
    {"referenzDatum": 2017-08-03},... },
    {"referenzDatum": 2017-08-02},... },
    {"referenzDatum": 2017-08-01},... },]},
 {"monthYear": "07.2017":[
    {"referenzDatum": 2017-07-03},... },
    {"referenzDatum": 2017-07-02},... }, ...]}
```

Then loop over it with two nested ngFor to generate the html output.

Is there a simple way to achieve this? I tried to just push the old entry into the new array according to the corresponding monthyear whenever this changes, but that didnt work out, because references were copied.
then I tried the following code, but it doesn't really work for more than 2 different months and the code just looks awful.

```
var oldDate: string;
var newDate: string;
sortedLogLine.entries = [];
this.sortedLog = [];

for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
  newDate = entries[i].referenceDate.substring(0, 7).split('-').reverse().join('.');
  if (oldDate == newDate) {
    sortedLogLine.entries.push(entries[i]);
  }
  if (!oldDate) {
    sortedLogLine.entries.push(entries[i]);
    sortedLogLine.monthYear = newDate;
    oldDate = newDate;
  }
  if (oldDate != newDate) {

    pushSortedLogLine.entries = sortedLogLine.entries.slice(0);
    pushSortedLogLine.monthYear = oldDate;
    this.sortedLog.push(pushSortedLogLine);

    sortedLogLine.entries = [];
    sortedLogLine.entries.push(entries[i]);
    sortedLogLine.monthYear = newDate;
    oldDate = newDate;
  }
}
this.sortedLog.push(sortedLogLine);
```

Any suggestions as to how to do this more efficiently?

Comment: did u try [Underscore GroupBy](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do something like this would be `groupBy`. Javascript doesn't have a native groupBy method on its Arrays, but several helper libraries like underscore.js do. Alternatively, you can roll your own with `reduce`:

```
let getMonthYear = (obj) => obj.referenceDate.split('-').reverse().slice(1).join('.');

let groupBy = (ary, fn) => ary.reduce(function(groups, item) {
       let key = fn(item)
       if (!groups[key]) groups[key]=[]
       groups[key].push(item)
       return groups;
   }, {});

let entries = [ { referenceDate: '2017-08-03' },
                { referenceDate: '2017-08-02' },
                { referenceDate: '2017-08-01' },
                { referenceDate: '2017-07-03' },
                { referenceDate: '2017-07-02' } ]
let groups = groupBy(entries, getMonthYear);
console.log(groups)
```

which produces this output:

```
{ '08.2017': 
   [ { referenceDate: '2017-08-03' },
     { referenceDate: '2017-08-02' },
     { referenceDate: '2017-08-01' } ],
  '07.2017': 
   [ { referenceDate: '2017-07-03' },
     { referenceDate: '2017-07-02' } ] }
```

See also [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-javascript-array-of-objects).

Answer (score 1):

```
 var arrayOfDates = [
      {'referenceDate':'2017-08-03'},
      {'referenceDate':'2017-08-02'},
      {'referenceDate':'2017-08-01'},
      {'referenceDate':'2017-07-03'},
      {'referenceDate':'2017-07-02'}
   ];
  var result = [];

arrayOfDates.forEach(function(entry) {
    var date = new Date(entry.referenceDate);

    var day = date.getDate();
    var monthIndex = date.getMonth() +1;
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    var keyDateFormat = monthIndex+'.'+year;

    if(!(keyDateFormat in result)) {
        result[keyDateFormat] = [];
    }
    result[keyDateFormat].push(entry);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Lodash, specifically groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/#groupBy)

I believe Lodash is a better choice over Underscore.js, more details in [this blog post](https://benmccormick.org/2014/11/12/underscore-vs-lodash/)

Answer (score 0):

Probably use a hash table:

```
var timetable = {};

data.forEach(function(el){
  var d = new Date(el.referenceDate),
  y = d.getFullYear(),
  m = d.getMonths() +1;

  if(!timetable[y]) timetable[y] = [];
  if(!timetable[y][m]) timetable[y][m] = [];

  timetable[y][m].push(el);
});
```

Then you can get all available years, sort and display them:

```
Object.values(timetable).sort((a,b)=>a-b).forEach(function(year){
  console.log(year);
  for(var [month,entries] of timetable[year].entries()){
     console.log(month,entries.join("\n"));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const entries = [{ referenceDate: '2017-08-03'}, { referenceDate: '2017-08-02'}, { referenceDate: '2017-08-01'}, { referenceDate: '2017-07-03'}, { referenceDate: '2017-07-02'}]; 
const resultObj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
  const month = entries[i].referenceDate.substring(0, 7).split('-').reverse().join('.');
  if (!resultObj[month]) {
   resultObj[month] = [];
  }
  resultObj[month].push(entries[i]);
}

const out = document.getElementsByClassName('json')[0];
out.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(resultObj, undefined, 2);
```

```html
<pre class="json"></pre>
```